# How to install KDE connect in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, kde-connect

I tried this but failed. So any solution for 17.04?
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu

Comment: It should work as well for 17.04. It must be said it's far from ideal though because the PPA is for xenial (16.04) only, hence the need to change the software sources. Now, **you need to adapt the 2nd command by replacing any instance of `yakkety` by `zesty`.**

Answer (score 7):

**Write this into the terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-kdeconnect
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! For future reference you may find [this useful](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to get your point across. :-)

Comment: Bad move. This will add third-party repository, not official ubuntu and not kdeconnect developer's. Just some one else's repository, who packed kdeconnect into ubuntu package.