# Problem installing KDE Connect on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, kde-connect

I had installed KDE Connect on Ubuntu 16.04, but for some reasons I wanted to reinstall it.
So I purged the packages I had and now I'm unable to install it either via Software Center or via CLI.

I've tried http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/kde-connect-indicator-ubuntu  and  [How to install KDE connect in ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905667/how-to-install-kde-connect-in-ubuntu-17-04),  but they don't seem to work and I always get these errors:

```
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 kdeconnect amd64 1.0.3ubuntu16.04
  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kdeconnect/kdeconnect_1.0.3ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get 403 Forbidden](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304340/apt-get-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem, however that developer no longer has a branch for kdeconnect for xenial, so i ended using this instead https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-kdeconnect hopely would help others.