# Unable to install kde connect on lubuntu

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, kde-connect

System info

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Tried building [kde connect from source](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect)

after i  run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep kdeconnect
```

i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:kdeconnect : Depends: libqca2-plugin-ossl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried installing from

1. [How to Use KDE Connect with MATE on Ubuntu and Debian](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-kde-connect-with-mate-ubuntu-debian/)
2. [Install KDE Connect in Ubuntu 18.04](https://fazlerabbi37.github.io/blogs/install_kde_connect_in_ubuntu_18.04.html)
3. [How to install KDE connect in ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905667/how-to-install-kde-connect-in-ubuntu-17-04)

All the mentioned unable to launch `kde connect indicator` or `kde connect`

Please guide

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy kdeconnect` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you forgot to add *universe* repository. The `kdeconnect` package is [located in it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=kdeconnect&searchon=names) in all current Ubuntu versions.

You have to:

1. add the repository with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
2. install KDE Connect with `sudo apt-get install kdeconnect`

Comment: I get this `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.` on running `sudo add-apt-repository universe`